# Android Discoverable Listen For Incoming File

Tags: android, file, bluetooth

I request the user to turn on bluetooth and become discoverable for 120 seconds.  During the 120 seconds I will be receiving a file transfer allert from a different device.  I want to grab the text from that file.  Is the best way to accept the file and let it download to the Bluetooth folder, or can I capture it within the app?

Either way how can I throw up an alert message saying waiting for file, and when the file is received remove the alert.
I don't thing STATE_CONNECTING refers to this either because the state never changes during this process.

Currently I have a while loop with a timeout waiting while file doesn't exists.... Terrible I know.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using BluetoothChat sample ?

STATE_CONNECTING refers to the moment when you found a device and you are trying to connect.
To download a file, you will have to open a `BluetoothSocket` and in BluetoothChat sample, you will be in STATE_CONNECTED when the socket is open.

You can display an alert message at the very beginning of ConnectedThread, before reading in the InputStream, and cancel it in the InputStream loop, when the file is received. You can also implement a timeout if the file is never send.

I'm not sure to understand your needs, but, you can also simply send the string with bluetooth, and save it on the second device in a `File`. It'll be easier to implement.

Hope it helps

Comment: I have looked at the BluetoothChat sample, and I assumed things wouldn't work the same with the sockets because it isn't file transfer it was just String transfer.  In my case I am sending a file with a string in it from a computer.  I am using the bluetooth stack on linux to ftp to a phone with the bluetooth OPUSH channel and Bluetooth address.  As far as I know you can only send files with these commands.